# GWT css background image

Tags: css, image, gwt, cssresource, clientbundle

I use GWT 2.1.1

In package `resources` i have png images and one css file.

In css file i wrote:

```
.finishedTask {
    background: white url("tick64.png") center center;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 0;
}

.unFinishedTask {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 0;
}
```

Than i create ClientBundle interface extension. With this CSS and images.

Than in UiBunder view i try to change css style:

```
    textArea.setStyleName(isFinished() ? res.style().finishedTask() : 
res.style().unFinishedTask());
```

When this code executed css layout of textArea are broken but i see that `class` changed (FireBug). Seems bug in css.

Maybe somebody already tried do the same thing.

Comment: what do you mean by `broken`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should use [addStyleName](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleName%28java.lang.String%29) or [addStyleDependentName](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleDependentName%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `setStyleName` which remove existing styles.